# i am looking to get the date diff from two or more row in a way that first rows serviceto date - second rows service start date so that i can get diff

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

my data looks like this

| userid | completedat | serviceperiodfrom | serviceperiodto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00002cd9-94eb-4c06-a2c4-75253fd541b9 | 2020-11-25T14:20:04.293Z | 2020-11-25T14:20:04.200Z | 2021-02-25T14:20:04.200Z |
| 00002cd9-94eb-4c06-a2c4-75253fd541b9 | 2021-03-21T10:27:34.842Z | 2021-03-21T10:27:34.800Z | 2022-03-21T10:27:34.800Z |
| 00002cd9-94eb-4c06-a2c4-75253fd541b9 | 2020-07-24T11:22:12.410Z | 2020-07-24T11:22:12.300Z | 2020-10-24T11:22:12.300Z |

I need the date diff from `serviceperiodto` date of first row - `serviceperiodfrom` date of secondrow and it goes for as many iteration as it has these details for each userid

please help me i tried joining the tables using subqueries tried to create a pivot table but none of them seem working for me please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag`/`lead` to access previous/next item:

```sql
WITH dataset
AS (SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (1, from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-11-25T14:20:04.200Z'), from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-02-25T14:20:04.200Z')),
            (1, from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-03-21T10:27:34.800Z'), from_iso8601_timestamp('2022-03-21T10:27:34.800Z')),
            (1, from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-07-24T11:22:12.300Z'), from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-10-24T11:22:12.300Z'))
    ) AS t (userid, serviceperiodfrom, serviceperiodto)
   )

SELECT date_diff(
    'hour', 
    serviceperiodto, 
    lead(serviceperiodfrom, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY serviceperiodfrom))
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 770 |
| 572 |
|  |

Comment: the values  comes from a table and sometimes it may be more like for a subscriber who reacharge monthly there may be as many as 12 records for same id but with different id so we wanto check if user did not resubscribe the plan for more than 7 days if not then we treat them as churn user is there other way in which i can calculate the difference between serciveperiodto date and serviceperiodfromdate of next row

Comment: @ShrishSharma What does not work with the suggested approach? Please show example inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: HI Guru actually what i am trying to get is for every user id suppose we have 3 records/subscriptoin what i need to get it new subscription (if there is no previous subscription then its new subscription next what i need is when is he subcribed for next time so difference between last subcrption endate/serviceperiodto date - next row subcrptionfrom/start date third point is if the difference of time is greater then 7 days i will treat that user as Churn else he will be resubscription user.

Comment: Select T.userid, T.serviceperiodfrom, T.serviceperiodto,T.pretaxamount,
T.next_serviceperiodfrom,T.prev_serviceperiodfrom,
case  when date_diff('day', date(from_iso8601_timestamp(T.serviceperiodfrom)), date(from_iso8601_timestamp(T.serviceperiodto)))<=32 then 'monthly'
when date_diff('day', date(from_iso8601_timestamp(T.serviceperiodfrom)), date(from_iso8601_timestamp(T.serviceperiodto)))<=93 then 'quarterly' else 'yearly'  end, case  when date_diff('day', date(from_iso8601_timestamp(T.serviceperiodfrom)), date(from_iso8601_timestamp(T.next_serviceperiodfrom)))>=7 then 'Churn' else 'resubs'

Comment: end from (select userid, serviceperiodfrom, serviceperiodto,pretaxamount,
lead(serviceperiodfrom, 1) over (order by userid) as next_serviceperiodfrom,
lag(serviceperiodfrom, 1) over (order by userid) as prev_serviceperiodfrom
from list_payments_parq order by userid) as T

Comment: Query in two parth aded as due to number of character limitation this is the query i am trying to get first time subcribers , resubscribers and churn user but its not giving me desired result though i m trying lead and lag fucntion in single query

Comment: @ShrishSharma you can always update your original question.

Comment: @ShrishSharma you need to partition over `userid` and then order by one of the dates, please see my answer.